# MKMapViewDelegate subclass method not called

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, mapkit, subclass

I have a subclass class that conforms to `NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate`- and have assigned it to the  `mapView.delegate` property however the delegate method is not getting called. How can I properly subclass `MKMapViewDelegate` and set that class as a delegate?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class HomeVC: ViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView! didSet { 
        mapView.delegate = MyMapViewDelegate() 
    }
}

class MyMapViewDelegate: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

    print("Not being called")

    return renderer
  }
}
```

When I had the HomeVC conform to the MKMapViewDelegate - the method would get called. So I am assuming I am either not subclassing correctly or instantiating the subclassed object correctly.

Comment: The map view won't retain its delegate, so the delegate you create gets deallocated immediately afterwards.  You would have to save it in a property on your view controller.

Comment: Fuzzy on how swift deals with this, but this would be caused in objective-c due to weak references and the fact that you don't have anything holding onto the delegate object, so it is deallocated as soon as that function leaves scope... Just a thought...

Comment: @dan Damn... you beat me to it :)

Comment: Appreciate it! The small stuff are always the things causing troubles haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is be caused due to weak references and the fact that you don't have anything holding onto the delegate object, so it is deallocated as soon as that function leaves scope. Internally, an object should always have a weak reference to it’s delegate to avoid retain cycles, but if you want an object other than `self` to be the delegate you need something with a strong reference.

I believe this could be solved by creating a delegate property in your view controller so that there's a strong reference to that object...

```
class HomeVC: ViewController {
    let mapViewDelegate = MyMapViewDelegate()
    ...
}
```